# Angular2 Change Detection Infinite Loop

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

We have a simple component with an input property as such:

```
<app-example [exampleInput$]="exampleInputData$"></app-example>
```

On the component where we use `app-example` we have:

```
get exampleInputData$(): any {
    var subject = new Subject<string>();
    console.log("Log1");

    this.exampleService.getAllData(this.id).subscribe(data => {
      console.log("Log2");
      subject.next(data);
    });

    return subject.asObservable();
  }
```

And the `exampleService` is a simple observable as such:

```
public getAllData(id): Observable<ExampleObject[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}data/${id}`).map((response: Response) => {
      var data = <ExampleObject[]>response.json();
      return data;
    }).catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

When we run this it get's into an infinite loop, if we change the `changeDetection` to `OnPush` it stops or if we remove the call to `getAllData`.  Does anyone have an idea of why this is causing an infinite loop?

Below is the `app-example` component and the HTML template:

```
export class ExampleComponent implements OnDestroy {      
  private subscription: ISubscription;
  private parsedResponse : any;

  @Input() exampleInput$;

  getData(): void
  {    
    this.subscription = this.exampleInput$.subscribe((data) => {this.parsedResponse = data;},
      () => {
        // Here we download the data as CSV
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.subscription) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
```

Template:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="getData()">
  Download As CSV
</button>
```

Comment: Show your usage of `getAllData` and `exampleInputData$`

Comment: I have added the example component and where that is used, I am not sure about getAllData as I have shown how this is used but happy to add more data if you can explain what I have missed?

Answer (score 2):

You are binding a method in the HTML. So in every change detection the method will be invoked. You need to set the observable like an attribute and the content in the exampleInputData$() put it in ngOnInit

```
export AppComponent {

    subject = new Subject<string>();
    observable$ = subject.asObservable();
    id: number;

    ngOnInit() {
        // I expected you know how to get the id value
        this.exampleService.getAllData(this.id).subscribe(data => {
            this.subject.next(data);
        });
    }
}
```

And the HTML

```
<app-example [exampleInput$]="observable$"></app-example>
```

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks for the response, do you have a simple example of what you mean?  We are hoping this will be lazy-loaded and we won't actually get the data until they click the button so don't want to load all the data OnInit unless they want to export to CSV

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the rest of your code goes, but I think you may be calling exampleInputData$ in each render, you should do something like this:

```
Class Component implements OnInit {
    constructor(exampleInputDataService: ExampleInputDataService) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.data = this.exampleInputDataService.getData();
    }
}
```